# Using AsyncTask for PCM AudioTrack playback without freezing activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i could need some help with that. here is the problem and what i have done until now.

**problem:**

i want to play a pcm file that i recorded before. as this file can be larger, i play it by using audiotrack. this works quite nice. but i dont want the activity to freeze. i already tried thread and so on, now im working on the asynctask but the activity still is not responding.

**this is what i got:**

in the ui activity, i create a new waveplayer object and try to run it.

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    /**
     * Handles ShortClicks for ListView
     */
    OnItemClickListener itemlistener = new OnItemClickListener(){

        MediaPlayer mp=null;
        String currentlyplaying = null;

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adaptview, View clickedview, int position,
                long id) {

            String pathtofile = (String) adaptview.getItemAtPosition(position);
            if(pathtofile.contains(".wav"))
            {
                //HQ!
                if(mp==null)
                {
                    clickedview.setSelected(true);
                    try
                    {

                        WavePlayer t = null;
                        //TODO: //add thread waveplayer to play file!
                        try {
                            t = new WavePlayer(pathtofile);
                            t.execute((Void)null);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        clickedview.postDelayed(new Deselector(clickedview, t), 1000);

                        currentlyplaying = pathtofile;


                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                }
                else
                {

                }

            }
            else{
                //NO HQ
                //you dont need to know that :)


            }


        }
    };
```

the class deselector:

```
/**
 * This Runnable tries to deselect the view after playing the audio file.
 * @author quant
 *
 */
class Deselector implements Runnable
{
    View view = null;
    AsyncTask thread;

    Deselector(View view, AsyncTask t)
    {
        this.view = view ; 
        this.thread = t;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            view.setSelected(false);
            thread.cancel(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

everything concerning playback works nice, i can hear my voice and the playback itself works fine... but still the gui in the main activity does freeze/is not responding.

hope someone can help.

thanks in advance

markus

Comment: thank you so much for editing, the code tag simply does not work so nice for me :(

Comment: copied into eclipse, ctrl+i, and back :')

Comment: originally this came from my eclipse.. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by using a remote service. i'm happy with this solution because i had one running for other purpose yet. now the interface is responsive again.